# akka actors: No response for given command line argument with sbt

Tags: scala, twitter, cassandra, akka, twitter-search

I am running an application involving akka actors with cassandra.This app takes the scan tweets on a hashatag, write them to cassandra and read them from cassandra. The three actions (1) Scanning tweets (2) Reading tweets (3) Writing tweets. are user choices during run time. They are incorporation in  `Main` object as shown below.

**Main.scala**

```
package core

import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem}
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import core.TweetReaderActor.{CountAll, FindAll}

object Main extends App with ConfigCassandraCluster {
  import Commands._
  import akka.actor.ActorDSL._

  def twitterSearchProxy(query: String) = s"http://twitter-search-proxy.herokuapp.com/search/tweets?q=$query"

  implicit lazy val system = ActorSystem()
  val write = system.actorOf(Props(new TweetWriterActor(cluster)))
  val read = system.actorOf(Props(new TweetReaderActor(cluster)))
  val scan = system.actorOf(Props(new TweetScannerActor(write, twitterSearchProxy)))

  // we don't want to bother with the ``ask`` pattern, so
  // we set up sender that only prints out the responses to
  // be implicitly available for ``tell`` to pick up.
  implicit val _ = actor(new Act {
    become {
      case x => println(">>> " + x)
    }
  })

  @tailrec
  private def commandLoop(): Unit = {
    Console.readLine() match {
      case QuitCommand                => return
      case ScanCommand(query)         => scan ! query.toString

      case ListCommand(count)         => read ! FindAll(count.toInt)
      case CountCommand               => read ! CountAll
      case _                          => return
    }

    commandLoop()
  }

  // start processing the commands
  commandLoop()

  // when done, stop the ActorSystem
  system.shutdown()

}

/**
 * Various regexes for the ``Shell`` to use
 */
object Commands {

  val ListCommand  = "list (\\d+)".r
  val CountCommand = "count"
  val QuitCommand  = "quit"
  val ScanCommand  = "scan (.*)".r

}
```

but when i am running the app with `scan(hashtag)` as a command line argumnet, the program keeps idle.

```
C:\Akka Actors\activator-akka-cassandra-master>sbt run scan(spyder)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Akka Actors\activator-akka-cassandra-master\project
[info] Set current project to activator-akka-cassandra (in build file:/C:/Akka%20Actors/activator-akka-cassandra-master/)
[info] Running core.Main
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

No action.No errors.

below is some portion of **tweetscan.scala** an actor which takes by passed `"query"` string through `Main` object and performs the marshaling.

```
class TweetScannerActor(tweetWrite: ActorRef, queryUrl: String => String) extends Actor with TweetMarshaller {
  import context.dispatcher
  import akka.pattern.pipe

  private val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[Tweets]

  def receive: Receive = {
    case query: String => pipeline(Get(queryUrl(query))) pipeTo tweetWrite
  }
}
```

Is there any thing wrong in the process i follow in giving the Command line arguments while `sbt run` !
Any suggestions are appreciable, where it gone wrong.I could provide more details if needed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code into a fat jar and testing? I had some troubles with `sbt run` and working with piped data before.

Comment: @JuanStiza I was able to get the work done by giving the command line argument after the normal `sbt run` kicked off the main method.its just waiting for user to give the command once the main method started normally.